# Better URLS clashing with my controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an application that allows users to create and find new events. I'd like to pretty up the URL's and I'm using [this rails casts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url-revised?autoplay=true) as a reference.

The problem is with the controller part.. I have very specific code in my events controller and I hope that what he suggests won't cause any problems. Here is my current events#show action:

```
 def show
    @event = Event.where(id: params[:id]).first
    if @event.present?
      @user = current_user
      # @event = Event.find(params[:id])
      @owner = @event.user
      @participants = @event.participants
      @waiting_participants = @event.waiting_participants
    else
      redirect_to events_path, error: 'Event not found'
    end
  end
```

And Ryan suggests that I change the find line to:

```
def show
  @event = find_by_slug!(params[:id])
  ....the rest of my code here
end
```

As you can see I'm finding the events slightly differently with:

```
def show
  @event = Event.where(id: params[:id]).first
  ....the rest of my code here
end
```

How can I get his way to work without messing up my code?

Cheers!

**Update:**

```
def update
     @event = current_user.events.find(params[:id])
    if @event.update_attributes(params[:event])
      @event.update_event_date
      flash[:success] = "Event updated."
      redirect_to @event
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Comment: You could simplifying your actions quite a bit by just using `@vent = Event.find(params[:id])` and allowing the exception to do its job.

Comment: Thanks! Care to expand a bit on that in an answer form? Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your show view should really ever only be 'showing' a single item. Your code:

```
@event = Event.where(id: params[:id]).first
```

...would be better expressed as:

```
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
```

Your original code returns an ActiveRecord::Relation object (basically an array) containing a single object. Since you're finding an object with its ID, which is auto-generated when a record is created, the ID will always be unique.

If you follow Ryan's cast correctly, each record will have a unique slug name associated with it. Your code should be just fine if you follow his tutorial correctly.

Comment: Got it - thanks! Updated my original post. The only thing that is a bit confusing is that my update action has current_user.events.find(params[:id]). Where as my show, and destroy actions has the typical event.find(params[:id]). Will this be a problem? Cheers.

Comment: As long as your routes to those methods don't change, you should be fine. It's always hard to tell with somebody else's app, but just do as I do - break it until it stops breaking :)